# How to create choice parameter for load test?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

we have jenkins pipeline written on groovy script from code checkout, image build, unit test, code quality,securityscan, push to registry and load test

my requirement is as load test stages should be in option while triggering build. bcoz load test taking more time..
so when developer wants to build trigger there should be option like load test Yes or no.. if yes means it should ask auth value then should run if no means build run without load test

please help me on this how to do this with choice/option parameter or else any other suggest ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried checking the box for "this project is parameterized" in your job config?